# В чем моя ошибка? [Unity 3D]

Tags: c#, unity3d, исключения

Есть [код](https://pastebin.com/vZ71Y9fV)(длинный, потому на пастебине):

Юнити на него ругается, мол "Null Reference Exception". Вроде бы всеми способами его пытался решить, но у меня не получилось. Попрошу тыкнуть меня носом в ошибку, как кота. Смотреть нужно на части:

```
public float Distance;
public float TracerLength;
public float Speed;
public GameObject muzzle;
public Material mat;
Vector3 scale = new Vector3(0.025f, 0.025f, 0.025f);
GameObject bl = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

MeshRenderer mr = bl.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>() as MeshRenderer;
Transform tf = bl.AddComponent<Transform>() as Transform;
bl.renderer.material = mat;
bl.renderer.material.color = IlluminCol;

if(scale.z < TracerLength){
     scale.z += Speed * Time.deltaTime;
}else{
     bl.transform.Translate(0, 0, Speed);
     if(Vector3.Distance(bl.transform.position, muzzle.transform.position) > Distance){
          GameObject.Destroy(bl);   
     }
}
```

Где-то в них есть ошибка, но я не пойму, где она. Гугл не помогает совершенно.
И да, прошу прощения за ужасный код. Я только учусь ©

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось путем просто создания поля bl без его определения и его определения в методе Start()